# Javascript function not being executed after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, function, submit

I have a form and want to execute this function after the submit button has been pressed:

```
function bereken() {


    if(document.getElementById('v1_1').checked)  {
        c = c - 0
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_2').checked)  {
        c += 1;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_3').checked)  {
        c += 2;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_4').checked)  {
        c += 3;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_5').checked){
        c += 4;
    }

        var naam = document.getElementById('naamTxt').value;
    var percentages = "C: " + c/40*100 + "%. S: " + s/40*100 + "%. G: "+ g/40*100 + "%. E:" + e/20*100 + "%. I= " + i/20*100 + "%";
    var antwoorden = "1. Ik ben spontaan =" +   $('input[name=v1]:checked', '#myForm').val() + " 2. Mijn gedachten zijn ordelijk = " + $('input[name=v1]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    var li = document.getElementById("klasDown");
    var klas = li.options[li.selectedIndex].value;


    alert(klas + ", "+ naam + " = C: " + c/40*100 + "%. S: " + s/40*100 + "%. G: "+ g/40*100 + "%. E:" + e/20*100 + "%. I= " + i/20*100 + "% " + "1. Ik ben spontaan =" +   $('input[name=v1]:checked', '#myForm').val() + " 2. Mijn gedachten zijn ordelijk = " + $('input[name=v1]:checked', '#myForm').val());
     }
```

I have tried different methods, exploring through the similar questions on this site, but with no succes. Can someone point out why it is not being fired?

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return bereken()" >
Volledige naam: <input name="naamTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="naamTxt" class="searchField"/> <br>
Klas: <select name="klasDown">
  <option value="H4A" selected="selected">H4A</option>
  <option value="H4B" >H4B</option>
  <option value="H4C">H4C</option>
  <option value="H4C">H4D</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4A</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4B</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4C</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4D</option>
</select> 
</div>



<br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="bereken()">
</form>
```

I have tried onsubmit, onclick etc..

Comment: Your current code does execute the function. But, you have syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you're not preventing the default behaviour of the browser by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return` with either `false` or `true` accordingly.

```
function [...](e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...]
}
```

Change,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="bereken()">
```

to,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="bereken(event)">
```

To pass the event argument for inline event listeners.

Comment: @JeremyThille how about now?

Comment: Uh, I was expecting `function bereken(event) { event.preventDefault()`

Comment: You fought for it :)

Comment: It is firing now indeed, however, I get this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null, with this line:
var klas = li.options[li.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: @user3660293 that is happening because you have errors withing your code.

Comment: But, this is the right way to get the value of the selected value in a drop down menu? var li = document.getElementById("klasDown");
        var klas = li.options[li.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced the name attribute with "id", and it worked

Comment: Can you elaborate on why code in a function that is supposedly not being executed changes whether it is being executed or not?

Comment: By the way, now is the form not being submitted as a sql stmt, it only executes the JS function

Comment: The code in the function was being executed but not quick enough because the once the form is submitted the page changes, now though it executes the preventDefault which stops it from being submitted.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work if you use jQuery.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your code here
});
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the original code is using jQuery.

Comment: *I think this should work if you use jQuery.* - Actually it can work if you use vanilla (plain Jane) JavaScript too.